# javascript fetch api not working and giving error

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

i am using javascript to call a url. but is is giving me error in chrome console (F12)

please help me.

i expected a result

```
fetch(url).than((res) => {
  console.log(res.JSON())
})
```

but got an error instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a typo.
Simply use `then` instead of `than`
and `.json()` instead of `.JSON()`

```
fetch(URL).then(res => {
  console.log(res.json())
})
```

learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Typo questions generally aren't going to help future readers. Avoid answering these and prefer flagging for closure instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling error. It should be **.then** not .than